# inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CHAR

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a senario where, I have the following Where Clause in my query. I am using `Oracle 11g (11.2.0.1)`

```
select * from aTable WHERE (attribute_name IN 
(SELECT * FROM TABLE(CAST(:pbindvar AS CHARTABLETYPE)))or :pbindvar IS NULL)
```

The value for this bind variable is a array, but when I am trying to pass a null value to this bindvariable I am getting the following error
`Expected - Got Char Error`
Could anyone please let me know how am I supposed to pass a `null` value to this `Bind` variable so that the query will return me all the set of rows without applying the where condition.

Stack trace is as follows

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I tried the following as well but with no luck still getting the same exception

I tried with the conditional `where` clause still getting the same error

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN :pbindvar is NULL THEN 1 
WHEN attribute_name IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(CAST(:pbindvar AS CHARTABLETYPE))) THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) = 1
```

If I change the second condition `where` clause as mentioned below, the query is returning with all rows

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN :pbindvar is NULL THEN 1 
WHEN attribute_name IN (:pbindvar) THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
    END) = 1
```

Sample Query using hr schema

```
select * from Departments where department_name in (Select * from table(cast(:pbindvar as CHARTABLETYPE))) or :pbindvar is Null;
```

create query for type

```
create or replace type chartabletype 
as table of VARCHAR2(4000);
```

The issue occurs only when the **null** is passed to bind variable

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior in Oracle 11g using PL/SQL. Could you provide a [minimal but complete ("executable") example](http://sscce.org/) depicting your issue?

Comment: Could you provide example of :pbindvar?

Comment: @Ben Could you please elobrate on how to do this? since i am fairly new to this .

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I have added a sample query with which we are facing the issue. I am getting this problem by just running the plain query from sql developer. Could you please tell me the version Oracle u r running . I am running 11.2.0.3

Comment: don't use `select *` inside the subquery, nominate ONLY the column needed for the comparison. &/or I presume that table function works independent of that IN()